# How to properly escape $ in macros of Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am writing a Makefile in which I have a function which is called in `foreach`.
In this function, I want to use `awk` command in which I would like to use `$3`.
However, I do not know how to correctly escape `$`.

Here is the simplified code. (the `input.txt` have three columns and the third column is a value)

```
define MyFunction
%/filtered$(1).txt: %/input.txt
    cat $$*/input.txt | awk '{ if ($$3 < $(1)) print }'

endef

$(foreach threshold,1 2 3,$(eval $(call MyFunction,$(threshold))))
```

When I execute the above code, I get an error

`awk: syntax error at source line 1`

I have tried to modify the number of `$`s, or escaping with backslash `\`. It did not help...

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `call` function will evaluate the macro once, then when the recipe is run it will be evaluated again, then the awk command needs to see the `$`.  So you have to escape it *twice*, using `$$$$`:

```
define MyFunction
%/filtered$(1).txt: %/input.txt
        cat $$*/input.txt | awk '{ if ($$$$3 < $(1)) print }'

endef
```

If you want to see what make is parsing a good trick is to replace your `eval` with `info`:

```
$(foreach threshold,1 2 3,$(info $(call MyFunction,$(threshold))))
$(foreach threshold,1 2 3,$(eval $(call MyFunction,$(threshold))))
```